# Should JavaScript Event Handlers Be Unit Tested

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

There are a lot of questions here about unit test event handlers in other languages, but I haven't been able to find a good answer when it comes to JavaScript. Specifically I'm talking about a case like:

```
// inside a "view" class definition:
handleCheckboxClick: function() {
    this.relevantData.toggleSomeValue();
    return false;
}

// later on:
$('#someCheckbox').on('click', view.handleCheckboxClick);
```

Clearly there is logic in the event handler (`this.relevantData.toggleSomeValue()`), but at the same time no other method will ever call this handler, so it's not like unit-testing it will catch some future refactoring-related bug. And in any given JavaScript codebase there are A LOT of these handlers, so it's a non-trivial amount of work to test them.

Plus, in many JS shops (certainly in ours) there are also feature-level tests being done with Selenium that would typically catch obvious UI issues (such as when an event handler breaks).

So, on the one hand I get that "unit testing of logic == good", and I don't want to shoot myself in the foot by not testing certain code if I will pay for it later. On the other hand this particular sub-set of code *seems* to have a high cost and low value when it comes to unit testing. Thus, my question for the SO community is, should JS developers unit test their event handling functions?

Comment: Unit testing is for sissies, write code that works! In other words, I think unit testing simple event handlers is a waste of time.

Comment: @adeneo How is an event handler different than other code, from a perspective of unit testing?

Comment: (Despite my previous comment, I think this is a better situation to be picked up by a UI / integration test.)

Comment: Well, I don't really care much for unit testing, but I do use it for larger projects that could have design flaws. For a few jQuery event handlers, not so much (not at all really)!

Comment: @adeneo I dislike writing unit tests. I wish my projects had more unit tests. D:

Comment: Please don't name functions things like `handleCheckboxClick`. Name functions after what they do, not how they're used. In this case `toggleRelevantData` might be a better name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This definitely falls under a matter of opinion, but I will go ahead and give mine :)

**No**

In my experience it is not cost effective to test handlers like this at the unit level. I usually end up spending a great deal of time standing up fixtures and triggering artificial events; this results in passing tests, but little confidence that my view will function properly in the real world (it isn't much fun either). I find that all that time is much better spent elsewhere.

Some sort of coverage *is* important though, and I try to achieve that with the following approach:

1. **Move complex logic within handlers into helper functions that can be tested in isolation**. Ideally these are "pure" enough that they can be easily tested in a unit environment. If they are not easy to test, forget about them!
2. **Rely on integration tests to test interactions with your views**. This is the easiest place to test a wide range of interactive scenaries e.g. "when I enter a message into the textarea and press the enter key, a new message appears", without the headache of artificially triggering the interaction. Not that writing selenium tests is my idea of a fantastic time ;)
3. **Relax.** Coverage is best measured in terms functionality tested,  rather than methods/handlers  tested. If you feel confident that the assumptions you've made about your application's interactions are "covered" — in one way or another — then you've done your job.

This is not true for all applications or teams, but it's proved to be the most effective thing for the teams and applications i've worked on. I'm interested to hear what others think on the matter.

Comment: I like this answer. Honest test coverage is the best test coverage!